# PersistenceUnitInfo [appName] has transactionType JTA, but does not have a jtaDataSource defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am new to WebLogic and fairly new to Hibernate / Spring applications, as my primary language is C# and my primary servers have always been Windows Servers, so please forgive any simple errors I may have.

I am having trouble deploying to our WebLogic 10.3.4 server.  It works locally on my WebLogic instance, but not on the remote server.

I am using Hibernate 4.2.8 for persistence and Spring MVC 4.0 for my web application framework.  The error I am receiving is:

```
Failed to load webapp: 'ncms2_May20.war'

Message icon - Error Substituted for missing class Exception [EclipseLink-28010] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635) - org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: PersistenceUnitInfo ncms2 has transactionType JTA, but does not have a jtaDataSource defined.
```

I am using a Spring annotation based Hibernate configuration file.

```
package mil.navy.navsupbsc.utilities;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.app.AuditInterceptor;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;

@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Value("#{dataSource}")
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", Oracle10gDialect.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setEntityInterceptor(new AuditInterceptor());
        bean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.app.entity" });           
                bean.setHibernateProperties(props);     
        bean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);

        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

}
```

My Spring Servlet XML:

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Could any of you assist me in getting this to work?  I appreciate any and all help.  Thank you!

***Update***

I did the following to switch it to JTA:

- added a JtaTransactionManager in the Hibernate java configuration file rather than using the HibernateTransactionManager.
- set the JtaTransactionManager property in the LocalSessionFactoryBean
- added a jdni lookup in the spring-servlet file
- added a resource reference in both the web.xml and weblogic.xml files
- removed the data source in spring-servlet and removed the reference to it in the hibernate java configuration file
- created a data source on the server

Still not working 100% though.  Will keep this updated.

UPDATE:  Here's a helpful resource that I've been using (http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/)

Comment: If you're using Hibernate, why your error message refer to eclipse link?

Comment: I don't know - I'm not referring to EclipseLink in anything in the application, though I know EclipseLink is installed on the server.

Comment: That's why I'm really confused.  Since I'm not using it, I don't know what to change in the application...maybe a server configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the information given in the answer by @Vlad Mihalcea to improve my code; however, it was not the reason it was not working.  One of @Vlad's comments that suggested looking for a persistence.xml file in the META-INF folder clued me into the answer.

Even though I was using the Spring configuration file for Hibernate, I had an old persistence.xml file under the META-INF folder.  I wasn't using it, but WebLogic was picking it up automatically.  Since I wasn't using it, I didn't have a data source specified in the persistence.xml file.  WebLogic automatically assumes any persistence unit is JTA if not specified as `RESOURCE LOCAL`.  I deleted that persistence.xml file, and it worked.

That said, I also fixed up my code to use the JTA data source as @Vlad Mihalcea suggested.  I moved all my configuration code to the Spring-servlet.xml file to simplify the configuration.  I'm sure it could be translated into the programmatic Spring configuration without too much trouble.

In the meantime, here is a working JTA transaction based Spring / Hibernate configuration file.

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="mil.navy.navsupbsc.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="NCS"/>
        <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="mil.navy.navsupbsc" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="NCS" jndi-name="NCS" resource-ref="false">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager id="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Note that I also needed to add references in the web.xml and WebLogic.xml files to the JNDI data source I created on the web server (called NCS in my application).

Comment: Great job, Laura! Thanks for posting the final configuration. Others in trouble will definitely find it useful.

Comment: I'm glad it's finally figured out!  It was frustrating, but it's good to get some more knowledge under my belt.  Hopefully it will save others some trouble.  Thank you so much for all your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't posted your persistence.xml JPA configuration file but it may contain something like:

```
<persistence-unit name="..." transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
```

When deploying on application servers you should benefit from their own JTA data sources and transaction manager support, so locating the jtaDataSource through JNDI should be your first option.

Your data source is configured with Spring:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

and that's not really a production ready data source implementation.

So, try to configure your Spring application context to make use of the WebLogic transaction management support.

Comment: OK - I think I understand the concept - I'll work on implementing it and hopefully get it working - I'm assuming it is something along the lines of creating the WebLogicJtaTransactionManager?  Any suggestions on good resources for how to do this?  I'm looking at some Spring documentation now (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html) but it is for an old version of Spring

Comment: This [web logic article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/programming/spring.html) might help you.

Comment: I quickly read it and I'll read it again to pull out relevant information, but it is referring to a lower version of Spring and is not using annotations or the autowiring with package-scans.  Should be helpful though for understanding concepts, so thanks!

Comment: The Spring 4.0.x still contains the [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/WebLogicJtaTransactionManager.html). The TransactionProxyFactoryBean are replaced by the @Transactional annotation, which should be applied to your Service methods. There is also this [newer doc section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24975/intro.htm).

Comment: Great doc - thanks.  I am currently using the @Transactional annotation, so that should be the same.  I also am changing the configuration now to use the WebLogicJtaTransactionManager, as well as configuring a JNDI datasource in the web server.  I'm going to update my question with some code as I work it out.  Maybe if I need help, it'd give an easy opportunity for that - otherwise, it might give others a place to start later in the future.

Comment: I think that would be great. Since I am not currently working with WebLogic I can only give you some tips, but if you manage to get it working, then others will be thankful for providing them an up-to-date solution.

Comment: Check also [this configuration example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416149/overriding-global-jta-timeout-in-spring-context-in-weblogic), it looks more up-to-date.

Comment: So I changed it to use JTA and am still having the same issues.  Since I am using Spring, I don't have a specific Persistence.xml file - instead, it is located in the Spring configuration XML file.  Does WebLogic require the actual persistence.xml file?

Comment: Persistence.xml is a JPA requirement. Spring doesn't substitute it. Your issue name is a JPA exception so you inherit the persistence.xml from somewhere. Check inside jars/META-INF folders.

Comment: Why did it work on other servers then without it?  Including the local version of weblogic?

Comment: Could the WebLogic server have substituted a default persistence file when it didn't find it?

Comment: There are still things that don't seem to match, like you have hibernate properties but the exception is "Eclipse Persistence Services" related to EclipseLink, which is a different JPA provider.

Comment: That's what I don't understand.  The only thing that has EclipseLink is the server itself.

Comment: The server has a default JPA provider of EclipseLink.  I thought I should be able to override that though with Hibernate JPA or my own chosen implementation.

Comment: I think you should make sure that default configuration is properly overridden by your Hibernate set-up.

Comment: I just read something about certain versions of WebLogic 10.3.x not being able to support other JPA 2.0 implementations...I'm using 10.3.4 - do you know if that is one of the ones that can only use EclipseLink?

Comment: I haven't used WebLogic for 6 years now, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: OK - I'll find out and post here what the results are so others can know.